# Function asks for input twice when it should do so only once

Tags: python, input

I'm currently in the process of working on a text-based blackjack game on Python for a course assignment, but when I run this code:

```
import assets


def show_hands(pl, dl):
    print('\n' + pl.__str__())
    print(f'Total: {pl.evaluate_hand()}')
    print(dl.hidden_card() + '\n')


def ask_for_bet(money):
    while True:
        try:
            bet = int(input(f'Your current amount of money is {money}, how much would you like to bet? (50 or up):  '))
        except ValueError:
            print('That is not a number!')
        else:
            while bet > money or bet < 50:
                if bet > money:
                    print("You don't have that much money!")
                    break
                else:
                    print("Your bet is too low! (50 or up)")
                    break
            else:
                break

    print('Alright! The game is on!')
    return bet


if __name__ == '__main__':

    print("-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_Welcome to Omar's game of BlackJack!-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_")
    print('\n')

    # Creating instances of both the player and the dealer, initializing the player's money
    current_money = 500
    player = assets.Player()
    dealer = assets.Dealer()

    while current_money >= 50:

        # Ask for the player's bet
        player_bet = ask_for_bet(current_money)

        # Deal two cards to the player
        print('\n' + 'The cards are being dealt...')
        player.add_card(dealer.deal_cards(2))

        # Show both the hand of the player and the dealer (one face down card)
        show_hands(player, dealer)

        # Continuously ask for the player's decision (hit/stand) as long as he chooses to hit and doesn't bust
        continue_hitting = True

        while continue_hitting and player.evaluate_hand() <= 21:

            hit_or_stand = input('Do you want to hit or stand? (hit/stand): ').lower()

            while hit_or_stand not in ('hit', 'stand'):
                hit_or_stand = input('PLease input a correct value (hit/stand): ').lower()
            else:
                if hit_or_stand == 'stand':
                    continue_hitting = False
                else:
                    player.add_card(dealer.deal_cards(1))
                    show_hands(player, dealer)
        else:
            if player.evaluate_hand() > 21:
                print('You have busted!')

        # Reveal the hand of the dealer and compare it with the player's
        print(dealer)
```

and here's the assets module:

```
import random


# -------------------------------------------------------------------------

class Player:

    def __init__(self):
        self.hand = []

    def add_card(self, card_to_add):
        self.hand += card_to_add

    def evaluate_ace(self):
        ace_value = input("Choose your ace's value (1/11): ")

        while ace_value not in ('1', '11'):
            ace_value = input("Input a correct value (1/11): ")

        return int(ace_value)

    def evaluate_hand(self):
        hand_value = 0

        for rank, suit in self.hand:
            if rank.isalpha():
                if rank in ('jack', 'king', 'queen'):
                    hand_value += 10
                else:
                    hand_value += self.evaluate_ace()
            else:
                hand_value += int(rank)

        return hand_value

    def __str__(self):
        hand_str = 'Your current hand is: '

        for rank, suit in self.hand:
            hand_str += f'({rank} of {suit})'

        return hand_str


# -------------------------------------------------------------------------

class Dealer(Player):

    suits = ['hearts', 'spades', 'diamonds', 'clubs']
    ranks = ['king', 'queen', 'jack', 'ace', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10']

    def __init__(self):
        Player.__init__(self)

        self.deck = {}
        for suit in self.suits:
            ranks_copy = self.ranks.copy()
            random.shuffle(ranks_copy)
            self.deck[suit] = ranks_copy

        self.add_card(self.deal_cards(2))

    def deal_cards(self, num_of_cards):
        dealt_cards = []

        for x in range(num_of_cards):
            rand_suit = self.suits[random.randint(0, 3)]
            dealt_cards.append((self.deck[rand_suit].pop(), rand_suit))

        return dealt_cards

    def evaluate_hand(self):
        hand_value = 0

        for rank, suit in self.hand:
            if rank.isalpha():
                if rank in ('jack', 'king', 'queen'):
                    hand_value += 10
                else:
                    if hand_value > 10:
                        hand_value += 1
                    else:
                        hand_value += 10
            else:
                hand_value += int(rank)

        return hand_value

    def __str__(self):
        hand_str = "The dealer's current hand is: "

        for rank, suit in self.hand:
            hand_str += f'({rank} of {suit})'

        return hand_str

    def hidden_card(self):
        hidden_card = "The dealer's current hand is: "

        for rank, suit in self.hand:
            if rank != 'ace':
                hidden_card += f'({rank} of {suit}) (hidden card)'
                break

        return hidden_card
```

It asks for the value of the ace (if the player gets one) twice, even if he gets only one ace, and gives something along the lines of:[image]

I've tried different things, but I still cannot find the answer to this problem, and honestly, it's making me really frustrated.

Comment: can you just set a break point in your code and step through it? That should give you an idea why it's hitting that section twice...

Answer (score 0):

Each time you call `player.evaluate_hand()` it calls `player.evaluate_ace()` which then asks the user to choose the value.

One way to circumvent asking multiple times is to save the value of the ace and only ask if the value is not already saved.

Comment: I tried creating a variable ace_value where i'd store the value of the ace and assign it the value of 0, then had the program ask the player for the value of his ace only if ace_value == 0, but to no avail...

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to use something as a value, then you should code it as an attribute, rather than a method that returns the value every time you call it. So if you create `hand_value` as an attribute, then you can do:

```
def add_card(self, card_to_add):
    self.hand += card_to_add
    self.hand_value = evaluate_hand()
```

Then you can replace all instances of `self.evaluate_hand()` with `self.hand_value`, and the player will be prompted for ace value only once, when `self.hand_value` is set.

Also, some things to consider:

When you draw a card, you're equally likely to draw any suit. So if there are 10 diamonds and 1 heart left in the deck, the probability that your algorithm with draw the heart is just as much as all the diamonds put together.

You don't really need to ask the player for the ace value; clearly, the player is going to pick 11 if they can do so without busting, and 1 otherwise. I don't have much experience in casinos. Do dealers actually ask players what value they want their aces to be? You should calculate the hand value without the aces, then do `max(rest_of_hand+number_of_aces+10*i for i in range(number_of_aces) if rest_of_hand+number_of_aces+10*i < 22)`, and give the result as the hand value (note that you have to make sure that this never results in trying to take the `max` of an empty set, but that shouldn't happen as long as the hand terminates once the player reaches a hand value of 21 or higher).